# wifi router not getting a signal from network switch

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, switch

Recently, I bought a Netgear 5-port unmanaged network switch to run ethernet cables to our PCs alongside the Wi-Fi router (Unifi U6). I plugged the ethernet cable from the wall outlet into the switch, which showed that it's transmitting traffic. Then I plugged the single ethernet input of the router into the switch, but no traffic went through. I connected another ethernet cable from the switch to my phone via an adapter to test it and the network seemed to work just fine.
I can't find any answers in the Switch's installation guide or online, so i don't really know what to do now.

Comment: describe how your network used to be set up and how it is now. is the cable from "the wall" connected to your ISP or to another part of your internal network? if the router was your gateway router and you put the switch in inline before it, that probably won't work. you would likely have to go from ISP > Router > Switch, rather than ISP > Switch > Router. please help us understand the layout.

Comment: Was the wall outlet previously connected _directly_ to the U6, or was it connected through a power supply brick?

Comment: the ethernet wall outlet was connected directly to the U6

Comment: from what i know the ISP gets distributed to 2 wifi routers but i'm currently not sure how exactly the network is set up. i'll take a look at the plan i was given and update the question

Comment: Plug the thing into the switch. Plug the switch in to where the thing was. - There's no manual for the switch because it wouldn't have anything to say other than *tab a into slot b.* - If U6s work like Eeros then that one port is for the (optional) hardwiring of *it*, not to send *out*. Neither of which are routers. - "ISP gets distributed *by a router* to two *access points*" ... unless they did this [Can I connect two routers to one switch?](https://superuser.com/questions/430006/can-i-connect-two-routers-to-one-switch) ... then you're in trouble.

Comment: Sure you had your wifi off on your phone and weren't using data? If it can't make a computer work, it ain't going to work your phone either. Also, wait. You can plug your phone into cat5... and that does something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unifi U6 <sup>(which is not a router)<sup>1</sup></sup> is a **[PoE-powered](https://kb.netgear.com/209/What-is-PoE-Power-over-Ethernet)** device – it receives DC power through the same Ethernet cable as it uses for data. Most likely the other end of the wall outlet goes either into a larger Ethernet switch that can supply PoE, or into a "PoE injector" power brick.

Your Netgear switch does not supply power over Ethernet, so the U6 can't function. You would need to find either a [compatible injector](https://community.ui.com/questions/PoE-injector-for-the-new-UniFi-U6-Lite/4b5ae6e1-c047-4f0b-8293-29af9feb426c), or a switch, that can supply 48V PoE using the 802.3af standard (and if you get a PoE switch, make sure it is not supplying power back *into* the wall outlet<sup>2</sup>).

Before doing anything, however, I would really recommend figuring out where exactly the other end of the wall outlet goes and what it's connected to. For example, if you find that it goes into a PoE injector hidden away in some cabinet, you could just move that over. (Also, since U6 is just an access point, not a router, you'll probably discover the *actual* router in the same central spot.)

---

<sup>1</sup> (It's a Wi-Fi access point – does not actually have the "router" half of a wireless router; it's just the "wireless" half of it. In your case this is good, as it means the actual router (wherever it is) remains upstream of your switch, so @FrankThomas's concerns likely do not apply.)

<sup>2</sup> (The U6 uses 802.3af 48V power delivery; which is also a good thing – it means the PoE supply that arrives at the wall outlet isn't turned on until a device requests it, so at least it won't fry your new switch. Older UniFi products used non-standard "passive PoE" that was always-on, which very well *could* have fried an Ethernet port that wasn't expecting it.)

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean that i could plug the access point into a PoE Injector that's connected to the switch? Basically Switch > PoE Injector > Access Point

Comment: @AlpineBoi: Yes, that would work just fine, as long the injector is compatible (i.e. 48V 802.3af or 802.3at standard, not the older 24V "passive" PoE). It's how these APs are often installed in smaller sites; Unifi "single unit" boxes actually come with a PoE adapter bundled.